# Trailing dots effect

Tags: unity

I am making a "Don't touch the spikes" remake in unity C#.
I want to make the effect of the dots behind the bird like in the image below. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Have you used particle system?

Comment: Look into Unity's particle system.  This is a very trivial thing to add to your game.  Add a Particle Component, and play around with it.

Comment: M totally agree with Jon as he said that particle system is a very trivial thing. So you will have to find some documentation and tutorials for that then you can sort out your problem. Best Luck

Answer (score 1):

Unity has a readily available [Trail Renderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html). That's all you need.
The Trail Renderer is used to make trails behind objects in the scene as they move about.
From the source:

> The Trail Renderer is great for a trail behind a projectile, or
>   contrails from the tip of a plane’s wings. It is good when trying to
>   add a general feeling of speed.
>
> When using a Trail Renderer, no other renderers on the GameObject are used. It is best to create an empty GameObject, and attach a Trail
>   Renderer as the only renderer. You can then parent the Trail Renderer
>   to whatever object you would like it to follow.

In other words, it is best to create a child object and add TrailRenderer component to it instead of adding directly to the main game object.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a particle prefab with the small circles as the image that get more transparent and smaller as they travel away. There's quite a lot more to it than that but to go into I feel would take an extremely long answer. Maybe when I get home and can take screenshots but there are a lot of tutorials on the particle  system that would probably do a better job than me